# POST request with body-parser (express.js v4.15.5, body-parser v1.18.2) doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, post, body-parser

I've the code,

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var PORT = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/*+json'}));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(200, 'welcome, ' + req.body.name)
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server listening on:   http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

When i send some data to this route "/" like POST request, body is always {} clear, i was using body-parser, extended: true and false, but nothing changed.

Test.
I sent this array:

```
{"name": "Petro"}
```

and req.body should be equal the same array, but i got {},

```
res.send(200, 'welcome, ' + req.body.name) //welcome, undefined
```

I want to solve it. For POST req i was using RestMan(PostMan), and was using isomorphic-fetch in react.js, so there is the same problem.

Comment: How are u sending data front front-end , your front end code?

Comment: `postReq() {
        fetch('/req', {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(
                [
                    {name: "Peter"},
                    {hobby: {
                            football: true,
                            backetball: true
                        }}
                ])
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(r => console.log(r))
    }`

Comment: now that's working! PostMan(RestMan) still doesn't work, i don't know why, but if i'm using fetch in react.js, it'a all work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already tried this...setting `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })` and making sure to select `x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman. Or selecting `raw` as the body type, typing in a JSON object for the content in Postman and omitting `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })` altogether.